# How to get screen width in jsp page?

Tags: jsp

I am not able to get the screen width on jsp page and not able to assign java-script variable to jsp variable. So please tell me any option for assigning java-script variable to jsp variable so that i can assign screen width to jsp variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting screen width as a variable in jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012158/getting-screen-width-as-a-variable-in-jsp)

Comment: The width would have to be posted back in a hidden field, or with ajax.

Comment: please tell me other option to achieve this.